# Realizar un contar.si en pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

| Orden | contador |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 102 | 2 |

Quiero que la columna `contador` sea como un acumulado de las veces que se repite cada elemento. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: utiliza df["Orden"].value_counts(), pero vos lo que queres hacer es agruparlas no es asi? Y pueden probar con la libreria pivot_ui

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con `df.groupby()` y `.agg()`, agrupando por la columna "Orden" y con `.agg()` le puedes indicar qué quieres hacer. Así, si tu `DataFrame` tiene dos columnas "Orden" y "contador", puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
df.groupby(by=["Orden"].agg({"contador": "count"})
```

Con `groupby` agrupas por "Orden" y con `agg` puedes indicar un diccionario con columna1: operación, columna2: operación, etc. Siendo operación sum, count, mean, etc.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema, la pregunta no cumple con los requisitos mínimos de la comunidad. Responder a preguntas que no muestran un intento por parte del autor incentivan la holgazanería.